# Angular 6 - How to access route resolved data from non routed components

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular 6 and have a non routed component that needs to access resolved data from a route I am navigating to.

Reading around I think I need to make use of router events to allow my component to know when a NavigationEnd event has occurred.

So far I have this in my ngOnInit():

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ).subscribe((route: ActivatedRoute) => {
      console.log(route);
  });
```

But when I look at the output in my console I only get a few properties like so:

```
NavigationEnd {id: 2, url: "/trip-schedule", urlAfterRedirects: "/trip-schedule"}
```

I have also noticed, I only get this event fired when I navigate to a state using an element that is bound to a `routerLink`. if I call navigate() on the router instance itself, I don't see any output logged.

Is there a different way I should be approaching this?

Thanks

Comment: If it's not a routed component, it shouldn't try to access anything from the route, IMHO. Why not pass the data as input from the routed component? Or store the data in a service inside the routed component, and get it from the service in this non-routed component?

Comment: I was just thinking it through some more after what you have said - so my route has a resolve on which calls a http service I have in my app. I'm thinking I could use a subject in this service and subscribe to that in my non routed component and then still be able to access my resolved data in the routed component. Does that seem like a logical approach?

Answer (score 3):

Route data can be read from ActivatedRoute as:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    })
    export class AppComponent   {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,) {

       this.router.events.pipe(
          filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe((route: ActivatedRoute) => {
          console.log(route);
          console.log(this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data);
       });

    }
```

but with this solution you have to know how deep and where is your interesting ActivatedRoute using some accessors root,firstChild,children,parent etc...
My example is simplified.